# US visa refuse twice under section 214(b)

Tags: visas

I am a executive grade officer working for Sri Lanka government & holding Sri Lankan Official Passport. Currently working as Municipal Commissioner for Anuradhapura Municipal Council. Anuradhapura Municipal Council is a member city of World Tourism Cities Federation (WTCF). Annual world summit of WTCF will be held in Los Angeles from 17-21 september 2017 and received invitation from Los Angelese Tourism & convention board to attend the WTCF world summit. The all expences should be born by WTCF.

I applied B1 visa twice and both applications refused under section 214(b).

I submitted official invitation, Recommendation from Ministry of Foreign Affairs, Sri Lanka.

What I can do next?.

Could I ask for reasons to refuse my visa or to whom I can appeal?

Comment: There's no reason to ask why your visa was refused. Your refusal contains those reasons and you've even written here that it's section 214(b), if you want to know more the linked (at the moment: possible) duplicate seems worth reading.